# adding prefix to mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

We are working on invoice management app, and we have added 2 columns to db Invoice no. and Customer id, so how can we give an unique no. to invoice like 2011/1 and for customer id how can we put Cust-1 ? even is there any possibility to start invoice no. from 1 again(like 2012/1) at beginning of each new financial year?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bizarre scheme, and there isn't an auto-increment for it, you'd have to manage it yourself (in general, the consensus to self-managing incrementing primary keys is : don't).

In your table, add in an integer column like `InvoiceID int NOTNULL autoincrement`. If you'd like to specify the year also, you can add a column like `Year int`, but I think a DateStamp column (gets the time/date when record was inserted) would be even better `DateStamp DATETIME NOTNULL defaultvalue: now()`

It is possible to reset AutoIncrement:

- drop the table and recreate it
- altering auto-increment, example `ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=2`

Comment: thanks for your answer, we are adding year as prefix to make invoiceno. unique and as we would have to restart from 1 on each new financial year so it won't have invoice no. 1 twice, now how can we add this as prefix and should be use php fuction for this or is there any my sql smarted way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking instead of having "Invoice No." as the column header you have it show "2011/1" in its place?  Also, if you have spaces in your field names its recommended to remove them, or add in underscores so you don't need to put quotes around them.

```
SELECT "Invoice No" AS "2011/1", "Customer ID" AS "Cust-1" FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT InvoiceNo AS "2011/1", CustomerID AS "Cust-1" FROM table
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but how to add those data to fields, means how can we prefix Cust and it should be auto increment, and we are adding YEAR(2011) as a prefix because it would be easy to find and all invoices no. can be unique.

Answer (score 0):

[auto increment documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) may be what you are looking for. Essentially, the primary key is defined for both columns, but the auto increment is on the second column.

Comment: @steve so do we use these columns id(autoINC and primary), customerid(autoINC) but how will we make it increment and how to add prefix?

Comment: I imagined that you would actually manually set the id - which essentially is your group field. The customer id would be the auto increment field. I don't think you can have two auto increment fields in the same table. Since the id column is actually data (the year), and has meaning, I don't think you want the db to generate it. As far as prefixing goes, can you add that in in your app instead of storing it in the db?

Comment: customer and invoices are 2 different tables.

Comment: and we are adding YEAR as a prefix to make invoice no. unique, as we would have to start invoice no. from 1 again in each new financial year so it won't have 1 twice as invoice no. i hope you got idea.

Comment: The big drawback is that this is method of autoincrementing on a composite primary key only supported by the MyISAM and BDB engines. MyISAM isn't ACID compliant, and BDB requires (IIRC) is a 3rd-party engine.

Comment: @Mark Baker should we do it manually like last_insert_id+1, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Set the column structure as such...

- invoice_id == auto incremented
- invoice_year == YEAR(NOW())
- invoice_customer_id == customer_id from customer table
- etc...

...and then display to the end users a concatenated id (2011-1-1234) in the view.

It really seems like you need to organize the schema based on your output.

Comment: thats great idea, but how can we reset it again means start with 1 by next financial year.

Comment: @seoppc - You shouldn't have to reset anything. Simply change your report query (SELECT ... WHERE invoice_year = '2011'). If you have to start new each year create a backup_schema and copy the main_schema. After copy truncate all tables in main_schema on 20120101T00:00:00. You can implement this through a stored procedure and a cron job.