# How to post an array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can we post following array to mysql(columns: id, date, amount)...

```
Array
(
   [date] => Array
   (
      [0] => 03/27/2011
      [1] => 04/27/2011
    )
   [amount] => Array
   (
      [0] => 5000
      [1] => 5000
    )
)
```

How can we get data(dates and amounts) from this array to post intomysql using foreach?

we are getting this array using following fields btw...

```
<input type="text" name="payment[date][]" /> <input type="text" name="payment[amount][]" />
<input type="text" name="payment[date][]" /> <input type="text" name="payment[amount][]" />
```

thanks for your support.

Comment: You have a 2D array, so I assume you would have to have a double foreach loop.

Comment: What level of knowledge do you have already? Are you using a specific MySQL extension already (`mysql_*`, `mysqli_*` or `PDO` perhaps)? Or is this a complete PHP/MySQL rookie question?

Comment: @fireeyedboy yes i could use mysqli, but i want loop in php before posting it to db.

Comment: @JCOC611: that's won't be necessary. Looping one element and meanwhile checking for the existence of the same index in the other element will work fine.

Comment: @fireeyedboy  can you post code please?

Comment: @seoppc: there is a reason if people are removing the ALL CAPS from your title, don't insist on that

Comment: @Matteo Riva why are you editing? Don't you want to see the source of array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the first subarray, and keep the `$i` index to access the second alike:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO things (date,amount) VALUES (?,?)");

foreach ($array["date"] as $i=>$_ignore)
{
    $stmt->execute( array($array["date"][$i], $array["amount"][$i]) );
}
```

Comment: what if there is count of 5 in array, so would it post 5 rows to mysql?

Comment: Yes, it loops over all array indexes.

Comment: @seoppc: You got three other answers for mysql/mysqli specifically. Check them out too. And please use the upvote arrow if you want to show your appreciation for the example code provided (in the other answers).

Comment: @mario can you have a look at fireeyedboy posted mysqli code, if its good to use.

Comment: @mario, i like your code very much its fast and small, that would be great help if you could update pdo with mysqli. thanks

Comment: I don't really know how it works. It doesn't have the convenient ->execute(array) interface. You will have to use the ->bind_param method from fireeyedboy's code. I'm not aware of shorter options for mysqli.

Comment: ok no worries, thanks! can you even help me with this question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436726/adding-prefix-to-mysql-data as i could't get a proper answer there. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$arr = $_POST['payment'];
$insert = array();
foreach($arr['date'] as $key => $date){
   $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
   $amount = (int)$arr['amount'][$key];
   $insert[] = "('$date', $amount)";
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(date, amount) VALUES " 
    . implode(",", $insert));
```

Comment: why are you using implode? as we just want to insert a new row with posted data

Comment: beacause with my example we insert multiple (all) values per one mysql_query execution.

Comment: how much rows would it crate in case of count(array) = 5

Comment: It would create as much rows as there will be elements in $_POST['payment']['date'].

Comment: thanks! can you even help me with this question please... stackoverflow.com/questions/5436726/adding-prefix-to-mysql-data as i could't get a proper answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mysqli version (untested, and I never use mysqli, but should work I believe)

```
// the sql statement for the insert
$sql = 'INSERT INTO yourTable ( `id`, `date`, `amount` ) VALUES( null, ?, ? )';

// prepare the query for binding to the placeholders later on
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $sql );

// bind some variables to the placeholders
$stmt->bind_param( 'si', $date, $amount );

// loop through all date values
foreach( $yourArray[ 'date' ] as $key => $value ) )
{
    // check if there is an equivalent index in $yourArray[ 'amount' ]
    // change to isset if you want to guard againt null values
    if( !array_key_exists( $key, $yourArray[ 'amount' ] ) )
    {
        // throw an exception of perhaps use some other form of error
        throw new Exception( 'missing parameter' );
    }

    // give the previously bound variables values for this query execution
    $date = $yourArray[ 'date' ][ $key ];
    $amount = $yourArray[ 'amount' ][ $key ];

    // execute it!
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: so would it create 5 rows at table in case of array count is equal to 5, i just want to be more clear about code. thanks

Comment: @seoppc: this code will automatically insert as many rows as your example array is big. The `foreach` loop loops though all `$yourArray[ 'date' ]` elements (and extracts the corresponding `$yourArray[ 'amount' ]` element) and executes the query on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysql_insert_array($into, $columns, $array){

        $column = explode(",", $columns);

        foreach($column as $c){
            $c = $post[$c];
            $v .= "'$c',";
        }
        $v = trim($v, ",");

        $query = ("INSERT INTO $into($columns) VALUES($v)");
        mysql_query($query);

        return mysql_insert_id();
}

$post["username"] = "Little Bobby Tables";
$post["password"] = "x' OR 1 = 1";

mysql_insert_array("users", "username,password", $post)
```

edit: Oh, 2D array, doesn't work with that.